# Bug with jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

This piece of code does not execute the code block inside the callback function for result():

```
var cityURL = '/myURL/path';
    $('#city').autocomplete(cityURL, {
        cachelength:0
    }).result(function(event, data){
       if(data){           
            $('#city_id').val(data[1]);
            $('#state_id').val(data[3]);
            $('#state').val(data[2]);
       }
    });
```

the value of input#city_id and input#state_id does not change, but the value for #state does change. Both are hidden input right next to their field:

```
<input type="text" id="city" name="city"/>
<input type="hidden" id="city_id" name="city_id" />

<input type="text" id="state" name="state"/>
<input type="hidden" id="state_id" name="state_id" />
```

however, if I put an alert, the values change:

```
$('#city').autocomplete(cityURL, {
    cachelength:0
}).result(function(event, data){
   if(data){       
        alert(data[1]);
        $('input#city_id').attr('value',data[1]);
        $('input#state_id').val(data[3]);
        $('input#state').val(data[2]);
   }
});
```

why is this?

**EDIT**: Scratch that, the values do not change even with an alert:

Comment: How did you check whether the values changed or not?

Comment: How do you know that the values of tine hidden inputs do not change?  Have you checked with a browser debugger?

Comment: Are you sure that those "id" values are completely unique on the page?

Comment: Well, ".val()" definitely does work.  You may want to do something like `console.log($('#city_id').length)` to make sure that the "id" isn't a typo or something.  Also you don't need to use "input#city_id"; because "id" values are unique, the tag name is unnecessary.

Comment: OK, this is odd. When I perform the operation when the Firebug window is open, the values do not change. However, when I perform the operation when the Firebug window is closed, the values change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected in my comment, it's just Firebug that's not updating properly. You shouldn't trust the input value attributes it shows as they're often out of date.

A reliable way to check input values is to just use JS and enter something like `$("#foo").val();` in the console.